# Warum bewegt sich das Präfix »los« von »loswerden« nicht bis zum Ende wie andere Präfixe?

Tags: sentence-structure

Beispiel:
Warum ist

> Das wird ihnen beweisen, dass man mich nicht so leicht **los wird**.

nicht »Das wird ihnen beweisen, dass man mich nicht so leicht **loswird**«?

---

*Los* ist ein [trennbares](https://coerll.utexas.edu/gg/gr/v_04.html) präfix aber es trennt sich nur durch ein Leerzeichen vorher »werden«. Wie wird das genannt und warum ist das so?

> ... mehr verführen sollte die Heiden, bis daß vollendet würden tausend
>   Jahre; und darnach muß er **los werden** eine kleine Zeit.

Comment: "Ich werde das Gefühl nicht los", dass die Grundannahme der Frage nicht stimmt.

Comment: Was sind das denn für Quellen? Beide Zitate, insbesondere natürlich das zweite, klingen sehr alt. Das normale *loswerden* wird im modernen Deutsch m. E. genau so benutzt wie es der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/loswerden) beschreibt.

Comment: @Rak Diese stammt Aus http://context.reverso.net/translation/german-english/los+wird und https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=los+werden

Comment: Das zweite Beispiel klingt ganz ähnlich wie der Bibeltext Offenb. 20, 7 *Und wenn tausend Jahre vollendet sind, wird der Satanas los werden aus seinem Gefängnis...* Das ist **nicht** das Verb *loswerden*, sondern *werden* zeigt hier Futur an.

Comment: Sehe ich auch so. Das erste Zitat ist m. E. einfach falsch, es müsste *dass man mich nicht so leicht loswird.* heißen. Die Quelle ist vermutlich nach alter Rechtschreibung geschrieben, damals hieß es noch *[...] nicht so leicht los wird.* [korrekturen.de](https://www.korrekturen.de/wortliste/loswerden.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

Sowohl *los* als auch *werden* können auch einzeln vorkommen:

> Endlich bin ich die Schmerzen **los.**
>   Wir **werden** immer größer.

Zusätzlich ist *werden* eines jener drei Wörter, die als Hilfsverben verwendet werden, um bestimmte Zeitformen zu bilden. Das Wort *werden* (oder eine From davon) wird zur Bildung der Zukunft verwendet:

> Wir **werden** in einem Jahr ein Haus bauen.
>   Ich **werde** in einem Jahr ein Haus bauen.

Diese beiden Wörter können natürlich auch gemeinsam in einem Satz vorkommen:

> Ich **werde** die Schmerzen bald **los.**

Man kann im letzten Beispiel aber auch anstelle des Adjektivs *los* das Verb *loswerden* verwenden:

> Ich **werde** die Schmerzen bald **loswerden.**

In der Gegenwart lautet dieser Satz:

> Ich **werde** die Schmerzen **los.**

Wie man sieht, lässt dieser Satz zwei Deutungen zu:

1. *los* ist ein Adjektiv, und *werde* ist eine Form des Vollverbs »werden«. Vergleichbar mit: »Ich werde groß.«
2. *los* ist das abgetrennte Prefix des Verbs »loswerden«, und »werde« ist der andere Teil. Vergleichbar mit »Ich falle um.«

Grundsätzlich gilt aber, dass sich das trennbare Verb *loswerden* gleich wie alle anderen trennbaren Verben verhält.

---

In dem Satz

> Das wird ihnen beweisen, dass man mich nicht so leicht **los wird.**

ist der Teil

> dass man mich nicht so leicht **los wird**

ein untergeordneter Nebensatz. Man kann ihn in einen Hauptsatz umwandeln, indem man die Konjunktion am Beginn weglässt, und das Verb an Position 2 stellt:

> Man **wird** mich nicht so leicht **los.**

Damit liegt hier dieselbe Konstruktion wie in *»Ich werde die Schmerzen bald los«* oder in »Wir werden groß« vor. Das heißt: Das Wort *»los«* ist hier ein Adjektiv. Der Satz beschreibt einen Vorgang, der jetzt, also in der Gegenwart stattfindet

Man kann aber das Adjektiv *»los«* durch das Verb *»loswerden«* ersetzen:

> Man wird mich nicht so leicht **loswerden.**

Beachte, dass dieser Satz, im Gegensatz zum vorherigen, im Futur I steht, also ein zukünftiges Ereignis beschreibt.

Auf deinen Satz angewendet:

> Das wird ihnen beweisen, dass man mich nicht so leicht **loswerden** wird.